# Understanding of Truth Tables and Logic

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I have the following truth table I would like to confirm that my understanding is correct for the 3rd column of the truth table.

[image]

If I recall correct p->~q

In plain english means P implies NOT Q is this correct.

Therefore

p = T and q = T

p->~q = F

**Explanation:** since P is True it implies q is False  Therefore the Statement is False

p = T q = F

**Explanation:** since P is True it implies Q is Not True hence it is False There the statement is True

**The same logic applies to the 3rd one**

If p is False then it implies Q is not False hence it is True which is clearly the case hence it is True

The last one is what I am a bit confused about

If P is false then it implies that Q is NOT False hence it is True, but here the answer to the statement p->~q is True shouldnt it be false?

Comment: Please use periods and punctuation.

Comment: The question isn't whether $Q$ is false or not.  The quest is whether $P$ *implies* $Q$ is false.  As a false statement implies anything, if $P$ is false than $P\to ?????$ will always be true.   You say "If p is false then it implies Q is not false".  That is not correct.  If $P$ is false the statement $P\to $ can imply anything and everything because $P$ is false and our entire premise is unfounded.

Comment: One way to think of it could be:  $p\to B$ means "every time p is true then B is true".  The only way for this to be false would be if there was a time when $p$ is true but $B$ *isn't* true.  So your logic for the third and forth should go: "Is it true that while p is true than $\lnot q$ is true.  Well, since $p$ is *not* true the entire premise is irrelevant.  But this is not a time when it is false (that can only happen when $p$ is true but $\lnot q$ isn't) and since this can't be false, it must be true.

Comment: $p\to ????$ means "when $p$ is true then .... something".  If $p$ if false then we can't say anything about what happens when $p$ is true because $p$ *isn't* true.  So is $p\to ???$ true of false?  Well, we can't tell if it's true but the only way for $p\to B$ can be false is if "whenever $p$ is true then $B$ happens" is for there to be time when $p$ is true and $B$ didn't happen.  That is not this time, because $p$ isn't true so $p$ and $B$ false *didn't* happen. So $p\to B$ is not false.  And since it isn't false, it must be true.

Answer (score 1):

"The same logic applies to the 3rd one". No.

This is something people get confused about when they first learn about conditionals.

"If it rains then the road will be wet"- so if Rain = True, Wet_Road = True.

But you could also have other reasons for the road being wet (burst pipe idk). In which case Rain = False, Wet_Road = True, but the statement "If it rains then the road will be wet" remains true.

If I was rich, I would give to charity; this is a true statement even though I'm not rich (and not giving to charity either).

In other words $A \implies B$ has nothing meaningful to say when $A$ is false.

So $p \rightarrow \neg q$ remains true when $p = F, q = T$ but not for the same reason as the $p = T, q = F$. A way to think about this is that since $p= F$ we never get to the RHS of the arrow in $p \rightarrow \neg q$.

Now given this explanation, do you see why the fourth one works?